# Need gem that allows java in ruby on rails app

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, maven

I have a ruby on rails app that needs to access an API. The api uses .net, ios, or java in maven. I need a gem to access java (I am not versed in java). Anyone know of a gem that will access java in rails? I have seen Jruby but from what I read that seems to do the opposite, access ruby in java.The API also is setup for .net or ios, don't know if it would be better to try a gem that can access either of those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this gem:

```
gem 'rjb'
```

I have used this gem to connect JAVA API, worked nicely.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean running Ruby in the JVM, if so, see [JRuby](http://jruby.org/).

If not, you may want to be a little more specific. Sounds like you have access to a 3rd party API or something like that, and they provide SDKs for .net, iOS and maven (which is sort of a package manager in java, think [bundler](https://bundler.io/)), but there is no straight forward way to running Java from a Rails application.

You may have to re-implement the SDKs in Ruby, which may not be so bad.

Comment: So you are saying I would need to "re-implement" the SDK in ruby? Sounds extra hard, any idea where to start? I don't know java

Comment: The app is a ruby app and the API is in java. I have seen the JRuby but it seems to suggest running ruby in a java app while I need to use java in my ruby app or is my thinking wrong.

Comment: @SupremeA you mentioned you are ready to switch to .NET or iOS (??). IMHO running an existing RoR application sounds much easier.